# How to reload interface from onLayout?

Tags: android, layout, reload

I've got this GUI:

LinearLayout

```
-TableLayout heading
-ViewFlipper flipper
    - TableLayout1
    - TableLayout2
    - TableLayout3
       ... (dynamicly added)
```

I change the width of t1 in vf.onLayout(..) but i'm not able to redraw it.... please help :/
Here is the code:

```
 @Override
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
 int bottom) {
 super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

 Log.i(TAG, "flipper onLayout");

 int idx = this.getDisplayedChild();
 Log.i(TAG, "flipper displayed child is: " + idx);
 this.heading.cols_widths = some_cols_widths;
 this.heading.resize_cols();
 LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) this.heading.getParent();
 lay.requestLayout();    
 }
```

This drives me mad :/

Comment: Not a good idea to change the layout on onLayout

Comment: @nininho ok, so where is a good place to update first view after layout the second view? :)

Comment: When you change/flip to the other view it will be layout and draw again, so no need to update the view that is not visible.

Comment: @nininho 
what do You mean by 'view that is not visible'?
I'd like to change width in Tablelayout (which is NOT in ViewFlipper) according to values from currently displayed table from ViewFlipper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is like nininho wrote upper:

"use postDelayed to call requestLayout."

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments, you want to change the "header" of your viewFlipper when changing the view. Since you're calling the parent and calling requestLayout, just move the super call to last, so you don't need to call requestlayout.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
int bottom) {
  Log.i(TAG, "flipper onLayout");

  int idx = this.getDisplayedChild();
  Log.i(TAG, "flipper displayed child is: " + idx);
  this.heading.cols_widths = some_cols_widths;
  this.heading.resize_cols();

  super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

Or you could make resize_cols() call requestLayout itself.

Comment: sorry for confusing, but.. 'this.heading' is outside of ViewFlipper. It's TableLayout which is up to be set depends on the one of table (currentrly displayed) in ViewFlipper.
Currently i'm trying to change drawing order by 

getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i)

but no effect.

Comment: From your diagram ViewFlipper and TableLayout are on the same level, so their parent is the same and super could work, but It's a linear layout so the Table already has been layout when ViewFlipper is and calling requestLayout during layout is probably discarted. So if you already know the column width in advance, call resize_cols() before changing the VIewFlipper or use postDelayed to call requestLayout.

Comment: So, the problem was that the heading layout was dependent to later generated layout of ViewFlipper flipper. The solution was to use postDeyaled (more specific I used just Post) in flipper.onLayout with heading.requestLayout().
Works perfect.. nininho is a god :)